# Length of side of maximum volume hypercube inside hypersphere

Tags: geometry

Suppose we have an $n$ dimensional hypersphere of radius $R$.
What will the length of a side of the hypercube be, that has maximum volume?

Comment: The tag "Dimension Theory" is reserved for something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An $n$ dimensional hypercube with side length $l$ has a longest diagonal with length $l\sqrt{n}$. If the hypercube fits inside a hypersphere with radius $R$ then

$l\sqrt{n}=2R$

You can rearrange this equation to find $l$ in terms of $R$.